# Different Product Pages Displayed when I Change URL Key From admin panel

Tags: magento2.2.2, product-page, url-key

I am using Magento 2.2.2 and facing an issue and trying to resolve it,While creating a new product or editing already added product when i change URL key of the Product from SEO block i get two different views On frontend on product page.

For e.g.:-1)If i enter my URL KEY as:-Alive - Fine Quality Cotton Mens Collared Neck T-Shirt it gives me following view on product page:
Case 1)Url:-https://www.fabrikaa.com/alive-fine-quality-cotton-mens-collared-neck-t-shirt
[image: This is correct]

which is correct.

Case 2)But,If i enter any other URL KEY let's Say alive then it gives me following view:- Url:-https://www.fabrikaa.com/alive which is 
[image: This is incorrect]

incorrect.

Now what i want to do is whatever i enter in Url key i should get view as i am getting in Case 1,how to fix this?
Any help would be appreciated.